# Erro no is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: react, typescript, next.js

estou utilizando nextjs, reactjs e typescript para criar um "projetinho", porém, faço a requisição da API tudo certinho pelo next, retorna tudo OK mas quando vou renderizar com map ele da os seguintes erros:

> Type 'KidsProps' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)
> index.d.ts(1411, 9): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>'

**No console do VSCode**

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, parents_name, parents_document, birth_date, age, address, reason, active, created_at, updated_at}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```js
 <>
            {kid.map((item, index)=>{
                return(
                    <div>
                        {item.name}
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </>
```

Quando eu tento renderizar apenas o **{item}** ocorre o erro citado lá em cima, estou tendo que renderizar usando **{item.name}** e eu queria renderizar todos de uma vez.

Segue o código:

```js
 import { useState, useEffect, ReactNode, DetailedHTMLProps } from 'react'
    import { setupAPIClient } from '../../services/api'
    import { canSSRAuth } from '../../utils/canSSR.Auth'
    
    import styles from './styles.module.scss'
    
    
    type KidsProps = {
        id: string,
        name: string,
        parents_name: string,
        parents_document: string,
        birth_date: string,
        age: string,
        address: string,
        reason: string,
        active: any
        created_at: string,
        update_at: string
    }
    
    interface QueueProps {
        qKids: KidsProps[]
    
    }
    
    
    export default function Queue({ qKids }: QueueProps) {
    
        const [kid, setKid] = useState<KidsProps[]>(qKids)
    
        useEffect(() => {
            const apiClient = setupAPIClient()
            apiClient.get('/queue')
    
        }, [])
    
    
        return (
            <>
                {kid.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className={styles.container}>
                            {item.name}
                            {item.age}
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </>
        )
    }
    
    
    export const getServerSideProps = canSSRAuth(async (ctx) => {
        const apiClient = setupAPIClient(ctx)
        const res = await apiClient.get('/queue')
    
    
        return {
            props: {
                qKids: res.data
            }
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Você já tentou dessa maneira?
O erro pode estar dando por tentar passar um objeto como children do elemento, da maneira abaixo você estaria passando cada chave como um child válido

```
<>
  {kid.map((item, index)=>{
   return(
     <div key={item.key}>
       <p>{item.name}</p>
       <p>{item.parents_name}</p>
       <p>{item.parents_document}</p>
       <p>{item.birth_date}</p>
       <p>{item.age}</p>
       <p>{item.address}</p>
       <p>{item.reason}</p>
       <p>{item.active}</p>
       <p>{item.created_at}</p>
       <p>{item.updated_at}</p>
     </div>
   )
  })}
</>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).